# Intellij Idea. How to pass jaas.config through tomcat server VM options?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, jaas

I'm trying to pass a path to `jaas.conf` through intellij idea tomcat server vm options.

I tried the following vm options:

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_BASE%/conf/jaas.config`

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE$/conf/jaas.config`

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jaas.config`

They all are not working. The error is like this:

`java.lang.SecurityException: $CATALINA_BASE$/conf/jaas.config (No such file or directory)`

The only solution that works is to use an absolute path to intellij idea tomcat server directory:

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\myUser\.IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat\tomcat_(1)_myProject\conf\jaas.config`

Is there a way to pass CATALINA_BASE in intellij idea tomcat server vm options?